# Starting Angular2 issue In Nodejs linux machine

Tags: angular

I'm trying to run Angular2 application in node server using `npm start` command.
Server is not starting up the application its throwing below error.

> app/modules/image/components/imageServices.ts(46,22): error TS2339: Property 'response' does not exist on type
>   'XMLHttpRequestEventTarget'.
>       app/modules/image/components/imageServices.ts(49,56): error TS2339: Property 'response' does not exist on type
>   'XMLHttpRequestEventTarget'.
>       app/modules/image/components/images.ts(61,22): error TS2339: Property 'response' does not exist on type
>   'XMLHttpRequestEventTarget'.
>       app/modules/image/components/images.ts(64,56): error TS2339: Property 'response' does not exist on type
>   'XMLHttpRequestEventTarget'.
>       app/modules/image/components/imagesCarousel.ts(47,22): error TS2339: Property 'response' does not exist on type
>   'XMLHttpRequestEventTarget'.
>       app/modules/image/components/imagesCarousel.ts(50,56): error TS2339: Property 'response' does not exist on type
>   'XMLHttpRequestEventTarget'.
>       app/modules/image/services/image.service.ts(3,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs/observable'.
>       app/modules/my-reviews/services/myReviews.service.ts(3,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs/observable'.

Using **node v6.2.2** version and **npm  v3.9.5** version

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue? I'm getting the error above when I'm trying to start the application in Linux machine, it works fine in Windows machine :(

Answer (score 0):

These are all typescript errors. You should post the corresponding code of your `imageServices.ts` and `image.service.ts`.

What I expect is that you have a call inside your image.service.ts which according to your code returns a `XMLHttpRequestEventTarget`, but it actually returns a `XMLHttpRequest`.

you should change your code in your `image.service.ts` to something like this:

```
getImages(): XMLHttpRequest {
   //..
}
```

On the other hand, one might wonder why you do not use the angular build in `HttpModule` to do your request.

In your `myReviews.service.ts` you should change your import:

```
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable"; //capital O instead of lowercase
```

Comment: hi PierreDuc, can you help to fix the below issue.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41842603/how-to-call-another-components-methods-in-angular2

Thanks in advance :)